# Auto-refresh for SonarQube Dashboard

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I have some continious Integration running with Jenkins and some quality analysis with Sonar and Checkstyle.

I want to display them in real time in my open space.

My problem is when Jenkins run a new job, it update the Sonar analysis, but the sonar dashboard does not move. and we have to refresh the page (F5) in order to display the new analysis.

**How can I force the sonar web page to refresh after each job ?**
(using sonar 5.2)

**And how can I set the Jenkins build instable when the quality is below a gate ?** (or when I have more than x mjor issues ?)

For Jenkins, no problem : we will use the monitor view plugin

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but as far as some kind of call to change the page without refreshing goes, I don't think SonarQube has this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can't force SonarQube to reload the page after each job. You have to do this by yourself.

Prior to 5.2 you could use the BuildBreaker Plugin, to handle quality gate violations. Unfortunately I don't know a solution for this in 5.2+ :(